# enable a user to sudo su to other accounts, but not root

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

I have been asked to implement sudo rules such that a non privileges user should be able to switch to other users but not root. i tried couple of things as below but with no avail.

```
Cmnd_Alias SU = /bin/su - root
%XXXX_GROUP     ALL=(!root) NOPASSWD: ALL, !SU, !ADMIN, !SHELLS
===============================================================
Cmnd_Alias SU = /bin/su - !root
%XXXX_GROUP     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, SU, !ADMIN, !SHELLS
================================================================
```

I have searched a lot but could not find any solution or similar questions. Can you please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't use) `sudo su`. In effect it says, "_Hello `sudo`, please can I have root? Ah, thank you. Now then. Hello `su`, although I'm already root please can I have root? Thank you._" You can use `sudo -s -u {user}` without needing to use `su` anywhere, which may make your rules easier too.

Comment: @muru I think the point is that they want to disallow "root" to be the target user of the `sudo` command, i.e. they want to be able switch between several non-privileged user accounts and disallow switching to root.

Comment: @Kusalananda ah, I misread.

Comment: @roaima, thank you, I suggested this usage "sudo -s -u <<user>>. Let me see how it fits their use case.

Comment: Depending on the configuration of `sudo`, the `sudo -s -u <user>` may result in an environment that has the $HOME of the original user but the identity of the target user. For some situations, that might be useful; in others, it might be undesirable. If your version of `sudo` is not out of date for more than about 15 years, you'll have `sudo -i -u <user>` which will be an **exact** equivalent of `sudo su - <user>`. It will always switch the home directory, and will cause the login scripts of the target user to be executed to re-initialize the environment.

Comment: @telcoM, thank you. we apply patches quarterly, so no issues on that side.